# How to read contents from file and rewrite contents into it in qt?

Tags: c++, qt5

I want to read contents from a file, then do some processing, rewrite processed contents  into that file.
But after I open file in `QIODevice::Truncate` mode, then the initial content is empty, but I need initial contents:

```cpp
QFile update_a_file("some/path/to/file.txt");
update_a_file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text | QIODevice::Truncate);
QString fileContents(update_a_file.readAll());

qInfo("trial info %s", fileContents.toStdString().c_str());
```

There is nothing from the output log.

So, how can I read contents, and rewrite(empty initial contents and write new processed contents) into file in one open call? Or are there some other file mode in qt?

Answer (score 0):

You are erasing the contents of the file when you open it with `QIODevice::Truncate`.

From the docs:

> If possible, the device is truncated before it is opened. All earlier contents of the device are lost.

Try taking these steps:

1. Open the file without `Truncate`.
2. Read the content
3. Close the file
4. Open the file again, this time with `Truncate`
5. Write your modified content.
6. Close the file.

Comment: what about `bool QFile::resize(qint64 sz)`